# "Preventing Stamina Mode from saving power in standby" with no wakelocks

Tags: sony, wakelock

I'm  developing a music player, and I found out that after playing 15 min on my sony xperia zr while on STAMINA mode, a notification appears saying "MusicPlayer is Preventing STAMINA mode from saving power in standby", even my application doesn't use wakelocks (the AndroidManifest.xml doesn't have the permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` at all)

I need an answer from sony if this is normal and how to prevent the notification from appearing

that's all the permissions that the app uses :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: No I didn't... Unfortunately

Comment: I'm trying to solve opposite task: disable Stamina mode using API (or prevent it from saving power), cause my game lags if Stamina mode is on. Has there been any progress?